# How to display out put when doing calculations in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to calculate two numbers and display them but when I click Calculate Total nothing happens and no numbers are displayed. I've been looking for a solution for hours now and just can't figure out why nothing happens when I click the button. If someone could help me out a little bit I'd be very grateful!

```js
function calcTotal() {
  var intValue1 = parseInt(document.GetElementById('Value1').value);
  var intValue2 = parseInt(document.GetElementById('Value2').value);
  var strOper = document.GetElementById('operators').value;

  if (strOper === '+') {

    document.GetElementById('Total').value = intValue1 + intValue2;
    else if (strOper === '-') {
      document.GetElementById('Total').value = intValue1 - intValue2;
    } else if (strOper === '*') {
      document.GetElementById('Total').value = intValue1 * intValue2;
    } else {
      document.GetElementById('Total').value = intValue1 / intValue2;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = calcTotal();
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <label id="lblValue1" for="txtValue1">Value 1:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
      <input class="formFields" type="text" id="Value1" name="txtValue1" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="dropdown" id="operators">
        <option value="+" selected>+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="*">*</option>
        <option value="/">/</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <label id="lblValue2" for="txtValue2">Value 2:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
      <input class="formFields" type="text" id="Value2" name="txtValue2" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <label id="lblTotal" for="txtTotal">Total:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
      <input class="textview" type="text" id="Total" name="txtTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <input id="submit" class="button" name='cmdCalcTotal' type="button" value="Calculate Total" onclick="calcTotal();">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your logic behind this code is actually working just fine. You just had a few syntax errors.

1. There was no closing brackets (`}`) for the if statement.
2. Also, you had `.GetElementById()`. You should've had [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) (the `g` is supposed to be lowercase).
3. Also, you don't need to have a `.onclick` event in the javascript, if you already have on in the html. I removed that for you.

It's fixed in the snippet for you.

```js
function calcTotal() {
  var intValue1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Value1').value);
  var intValue2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Value2').value);
  var strOper = document.getElementById('operators').value;

  if (strOper === '+') {

    document.getElementById('Total').value = intValue1 + intValue2;
  } else if (strOper === '-') {
    document.getElementById('Total').value = intValue1 - intValue2;
  } else if (strOper === '*') {
    document.getElementById('Total').value = intValue1 * intValue2;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Total').value = intValue1 / intValue2;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <label id="lblValue1" for="txtValue1">Value 1:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
      <input class="formFields" type="text" id="Value1" name="txtValue1" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="dropdown" id="operators">
        <option value="+" selected>+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="*">*</option>
        <option value="/">/</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <label id="lblValue2" for="txtValue2">Value 2:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
      <input class="formFields" type="text" id="Value2" name="txtValue2" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <label id="lblTotal" for="txtTotal">Total:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
      <input class="textview" type="text" id="Total" name="txtTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <input id="submit" class="button" name='cmdCalcTotal' type="button" value="Calculate Total" onclick="calcTotal();">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some error in your code:

- Missing {} for if block
- Uppercase GetElementById method, note that all function with `uppercase` are difference, also with `css` and `Id` and `class`.
- Redundant //document.getElementById('submit').onclick = calcTotal();

If you want keep last line you can edit to

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", calcTotal);
```

and remove `onclick="calcTotal();"` on button

```js
function calcTotal() {
  var intValue1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Value1').value);
  var intValue2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Value2').value);
  var strOper = document.getElementById('operators').value;

  if (strOper === '+') {

    document.getElementById('Total').value = intValue1 + intValue2;
    }
    else if (strOper === '-') {
      document.getElementById('Total').value = intValue1 - intValue2;
    } else if (strOper === '*') {
      document.getElementById('Total').value = intValue1 * intValue2;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('Total').value = intValue1 / intValue2;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", calcTotal);
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <label id="lblValue1" for="txtValue1">Value 1:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
      <input class="formFields" type="text" id="Value1" name="txtValue1" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="dropdown" id="operators">
        <option value="+" selected>+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="*">*</option>
        <option value="/">/</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <label id="lblValue2" for="txtValue2">Value 2:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
      <input class="formFields" type="text" id="Value2" name="txtValue2" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <label id="lblTotal" for="txtTotal">Total:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
      <input class="textview" type="text" id="Total" name="txtTotal">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      <input id="submit" class="button" name='cmdCalcTotal' type="button" value="Calculate Total" >
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```